# Get selected value of ComboBoxColumn in Datagrid (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

I implemented a DataGridComboBoxColumn in a Datagrid using XAML. I can access comboboxColumn1 programatically, but how can I get the selected item upon value change?

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dgData" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="131,93,13,101" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="dgData_SelectionChanged">
       <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Subject" x:Name="comboboxColumn1"/>

       </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Life Area" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding YourSelectedItem}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding YourItemSource}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding YourItemSource}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: I want to get the value of the combobox in the code, and not through XAML.